# Laravel Polymorphic One To Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-8

I would like to create a structure with models for exam app.

Basic models structure that i would imagine:

- exam

  - questions ( exam has many questions ) { i think that should be morphed table }
    questions should have option to add multiple type of questions that are specified bellow

    - openQuestions - question type
    - closedQuestions - other question type
    - .... - more question types

So I would like to have a structure like:

**exam** have many **questions** and to questions table, I want to add any type of model that extends my **question** Model which always contains 2 params ( 'question', 'max_points', and other fields specified for questions )

[My current database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7ENF.png)

I want to add a relation between **exams table** and **questions table**, between **questions table** and **closed_questions table** and **questions** to **open_questions**.

---

So what I have tried:

I added relations for each question type to **exams** model **morphedByMany(QuestionModelType::class,'questions')** something like :

```php
Exams.php //Model
    public function openQuestions()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(OpenQuestion::class, 'questions');
    }

    public function closedQuestions()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(ClosedQuestion::class, 'questions');
    }
```

I can operate on models but I don't think that's an ideal solution, or should I just leave it as it is.
I think there is a nicer way of doing this, but I'm not familiar with this.
Or should I just add a Relation that morphs over an array of all question types?
How it should work when I would like to extend app with a new question type?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add condition relationship to `Question` you can try the below approach

```
Exam::with(['Question' => function(MorphTo $morphTo){
        $morphTo->morphWithCount([
            ModelOne::class => ['openQuestions' => function($query){
                $query->where('id',1);
            }],
            ModelTwo::class => ['closedQuestions']
        ]);
    }]);
```

in the above code, we check if the nested model polymorphic model is ModelOne catch the `openQuestions` or if the relationship is ModelTwo catch `closedQuestions` relationship, also you can assign your constraints to using the closure